# Issue with sort adapter

Tags: java, android, sorting, listview, android-adapter

I have a problem with my app about schedule SMS. If I schedule SMS in order by time for example first SMS at 12:00 and the second at 13:00, my app works. But if I schedule SMS first at 13:00 and then 12:00, my app doesn't work.

I used a sorting algorithm but it doesn’t work!

Here's my code:

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int PERMS_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    TextView textViewTime;
    TimePicker timePicker;
    Button button;
    String name2=null;
    String sms2=null;
    long tempo2;


    int hour;
    int minutee;
    //int hour;
    //int minute;


    final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    public String sPhone, sSms;
    public EditText etPhone, etSms;

    public Button bStart, bCancel, bTimeSelect, bPhone;
    ArrayList<Sms> dataSms;
    ListView listView;
    public static CustomAdapter adapter;
    private static MainActivity ins;
    EditText et1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ins = this;
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);




        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        /*listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                    long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item has been added into your list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                //dataSms.remove(position);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Sms dataModel= dataSms.get(position);
                //dataModel.setTesto();





            }
        });*/

        dataSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataSms, getApplicationContext());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        //bCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        //bTimeSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTime);
        bPhone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCPhone);


        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            /*  if (hasPermissions()) {
                    // our app has permissions.
                    scheduleAlarm(v);
                } else {
                    //our app doesn't have permissions, So i m requesting permissions.
                    requestPerms();
                }*/
                try {
                    scheduleAlarm(v);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        et1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePicker");

            }
        });

    /*  bTimeSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "TimePicker");

            }
        });*/

        //};
        bPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://contacts");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });


    }

    public static MainActivity  getInstace(){
        return ins;
    }

    public void updateTheTextView() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            //  for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++)
            //  {

                    dataSms.remove(0);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            //  }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //Toast.makeText(this, "COUNT DELETE: "+adapter.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        //TimePicker timePicker;
        //int hour;
        //int minutee;

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //Use the current time as the default values for the time picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            //Create and return a new instance of TimePickerDialog
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }


        //onTimeSet() callback method
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            hour = hourOfDay;
            minutee = minute;

            et1.setText( hour + ":" + minutee);


        }
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void scheduleAlarm(View V) throws ParseException {
        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSms);

        String name = et1.getText().toString();
        String sms = et2.getText().toString();

        //PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        //Long time= new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+24*60*60*1000;
        //Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + 10000;
        //Long time= System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;

        /*Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putCharSequence("Number", name);
        bundle.putCharSequence("Message", sms);*/
        //intentAlarm.putExtras(bundle);


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutee);

        long tempo=c.getTimeInMillis();


        //Toast.makeText(this, "TEMPO: " + tempo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //for(int i=0;i<dataSms.size();i++) {

            adapter.add(new Sms(name, sms, tempo));

        //  Sms dataModel= dataSms.get(i);
           // adapter.sortByNameAsc();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "NOME: " + dataModel.getNome() +"TESTO "+dataModel.getTesto(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //}

        Toast.makeText(this, "COUNT: " + adapter.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        adapter.sortByNameAsc();

        for(int i=0;i<dataSms.size();i++) {
            //adapter.sortByNameAsc();

            Sms dataModel= dataSms.get(i);

            name2=dataModel.getNome();
            sms2=dataModel.getTesto();

            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);



        //  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        //  bundle.putCharSequence("Number", name);
        //  bundle.putCharSequence("Message", sms);


/*
            Sms dataModel= dataSms.get(i);

            name2=dataModel.getNome();
            sms2=dataModel.getTesto();*/
            //tempo2=dataModel.getTempo();




            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putCharSequence("Number", name2);
            bundle.putCharSequence("Message", sms2);
            intentAlarm.putExtras(bundle);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dataModel.getTempo(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));



        }




        //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm.putExtras(bundle), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));


        Toast.makeText(this, "Messaggio programmato!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}
```

CUSTOM ADAPTER:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sms> {

    public static CustomAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Sms> dataSms;
    Context mContext;
    Sms sms2;
    Bundle getBundle = null;

    //ArrayList<Location> data = new ArrayList<Location>();
    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtNome;
        TextView txtTesto;
        TextView txtOre;
        TextView txtMinuti;

    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Sms> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.dataSms = data;
        this.mContext=context;

    }
    public void sortByNameAsc() {
        Comparator<Sms> comparator = new Comparator<Sms>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Sms object1, Sms object2) {
                //return (int) (object1.getTempo() - object2.getTempo());

                return Long.valueOf(object1.getTempo()).compareTo(Long.valueOf(object2.getTempo()));
                //return Double.compare(object1.getPrice(), object2.getPrice());

                //return compare(object1.getTempo() - object2.getTempo());

            }
        };
        Collections.sort(dataSms, comparator);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

/*    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position=(Integer) v.getTag();
        Object object= getItem(position);
        DataModel dataModel=(DataModel)object;

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.item_info:
                Snackbar.make(v, "Release date " +dataModel.getFeature(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("No action", null).show();
                break;
        }
    }*/

    //private int lastPosition = -1;
    //dataSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
     //adapter = new CustomAdapter(dataSms, context);



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataSms.size();
    }


    /*  @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            return dataSms.get(pos);
        }*/
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
   // @Override
    public long getTime(long c,int position) {
        return c;
    }
    @Override
    public void add(Sms sms) {
        dataSms.add(sms);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Sms sms = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
            viewHolder.txtTesto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.testo);
            viewHolder.txtOre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ore);
            viewHolder.txtMinuti = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minuti);



            result=convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }

        /*Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        result.startAnimation(animation);*/
       // lastPosition = position;


        viewHolder.txtNome.setText(sms.getNome());
        viewHolder.txtTesto.setText(sms.getTesto());

       // viewHolder.txtTempo.setText(String.valueOf(sms.getTempo()));
        //viewHolder.txtOre.setText(String.valueOf(sms.getOre())+":");
       // viewHolder.txtMinuti.setText(String.valueOf(sms.getMinuti()));


        /*viewHolder.info.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.info.setTag(position);*/
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

MODEL CLASS:

```
public class Sms {
    long tempo;
    String nome;
    String testo;

    public Sms(String nome, String testo, long tempo) {

        this.nome=nome;
        this.testo=testo;
        this.tempo=tempo;
        //this.ore=ore;
        // this.minuti=minuti;


    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    //int ore;

    //public int getMinuti() {
   //     return minuti;
   // }

    //public void setMinuti(int minuti) {
   //     this.minuti = minuti;
   // }

   // public int getOre() {
   //     return ore;
  //  }

   // public void setOre(int ore) {
   //     this.ore = ore;
   // }

    //int minuti;
    public void setTesto(String testo) {
        this.testo = testo;
    }

    //int indice;

    public long getTempo() {
        return tempo;
    }

    public void setTempo(long tempo) {
        this.tempo = tempo;
    }


    

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getTesto() {
        return testo;
    }


}
```

Comment: “Doesn’t work” has become one of my favourite dislikes on Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and specify precisely in what way the observed behaviour is different from the expected.

Comment: It’s an awful lot of code. See if you can reproduce the unwanted behaviour with less. Best, [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).